# How to set buildConfigField parameters dynamically while building an apk through Jenkins

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have following fields in ProductFlavors of build.gradle,

```
productFlavors {

    Flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.example.A"
        buildConfigField 'int', 'ID', '123'
    }
}
```

How can i update these 2 fields according to inputs given from Jenkins.?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following steps:

**In your app level build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        appId="com.example.A"
        Id=123 
    }
    ...
}
```

**change your fields as follows:**

```
productFlavors {

    Flavor1 {
        applicationId appId
        buildConfigField 'int', 'ID', "$Id"
    }
}
```

**From jenkins pass the parameters:**

`gradlew assesmbleFlavor1 -PappId="${APPLICATION_ID}" -PId="${ID}"`

Where `${APPLICATION_ID}` and `${ID}` are parameters defined in jenkins