# How to read a config file which is under app folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-file

I am having a config fie `config.properties` inside app folder . Which i am using for build configurations in `build.gradle`.
I need to read this file in java code . But i can figure out the `path` should i use . How can i read this file in java code . code below gives me `FileNotFoundException`

```
 try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        File inputStream=new File("/config.properties");
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(inputStream));
        return properties.getProperty("BASE_URL");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using the same file in `build.gradle` and its working well . as below .

```
 defaultConfig {
    Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('config.properties')))
    def properties_versionCode = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
    def properties_versionName = versionProps['VERSION_NAME']
    def properties_appid= versionProps['APPLICATION_ID']


    applicationId properties_appid
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode properties_versionCode
    versionName properties_versionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

`build.gradle` part is working fine and i am able to assign properties . But i need to read the same file in a java class . What path should i use for `File`.

Config file looks like:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.0
VERSION_CODE=1
APPLICATION_ID=com.app.drecula
BASE_URL=https://reqres.in/
```

Comment: Are you trying to read it in your application?

Comment: Yeah the file is under `app` folder parallel to `google_play_service.json`

Comment: Can I ask what exactly you want to get from config file. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should put application specific file under assets folder and separate your gradle build configuration and application specific configuration. Add application specific configuration properties file under `assets/configs` folder. Then you can read it as follows:

```
  final Properties properties = new Properties();
  final AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
  final InputStream inputStream= assetManager.open("configs/config.properties");
  properties.load(inputStream);
```

If you still want to proceed, then only way would be to put the file in assets folder and in your `build.gradle` use

```
versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('/src/main/assets/config/config.properties')))
```

Comment: I said its working in `build.gradle` . I need to read it in java class .

Comment: I can not put file in assets . If i put file in assets then how will i load in `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Diazdiaz you cannot read file in both. If you want the file to be part of apk and use it, you have to put it in assets. Its not a great idea to use same file for gradle build config and application configuration. You should separate them.

Comment: Thats kind of need . I need to have a single file both weather its in `assets` of any where else. is it impossible to have a single file?

Comment: @Diazdiaz you can check my answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176769/how-to-set-buildconfigfield-parameters-dynamically-while-building-an-apk-through/50177203#50177203) Using this, you can write content to BuildConfig file and use it in your application

Comment: `BuildConfig` file is auto generated and should not edit .  I think it will regenerate on each clean-build . SO this is not what i am looking for .

Comment: @Diazdiaz Then there is only one solution. Put the file in `assets `folder and in your build.gradle use `versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('/src/main/assets/config/config.properties')))`

Comment: Yeah that can be an alternative way to do this . Thx Add it in answer . Also please look for the initial question if you find an answer the post it here .

Comment: Accepted the answer . But i am still in dilemma why how can i access the file under app folder. If its not possible then why? Let me know if you find answer to this particular question . Thx for your time .

Comment: @Diazdiaz you can refer to [this](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/assets-files-and-data-parsing) post. Basically you cannot access the file directly, unless you either put in res/raw or assets. The local directory on PC and directory for .apk are distinct

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's back to basis. First You create properties in `build.gradle` and then You create `buildConfigField` with custom fields.

```
productFlavors {
    play {
        dimension "MyDimension"

        Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('config.properties')))
        def properties_versionCode = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
        def properties_versionName = versionProps['VERSION_NAME']

        //...

        buildConfigField "int", "MY_VERSION_CODE", "$properties_versionCode"
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_VERSION_NAME", "\"$properties_versionName\""

    }
}
```

After You rebuild project, fields will be able to call from `BuildConfig.{FIELD}`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //...

    Log.d(TAG, "Version Name: " + BuildConfig.MY_VERSION_NAME);
    Log.d(TAG, "Version Code: " + BuildConfig.MY_VERSION_CODE);

    //...
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips).

Comment: Is that Simple ? I am so dumb .  I have already seen this solution but did not understand . Thanks . Now i get it . Going to write it on Stone .